# GCP creating an alert, budget and alerts option missing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-billing

I'm on the free tier on GCP and trying to create an Alert under billing as per https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/budgets#create-budget.  However I don't see the option `Budgets & alerts`, is it because I'm on the free tier ?

Also if I'm on the free tier if I accidentally try to use a service that gets billed I assume I will get blocked ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you upgrade your account with a credit card? Free Tier means that certain service levels are free. If you have not upgraded to a paid account, then you will be blocked from some services. If you have upgraded to a paid account, you will be charged.

If you have not upgraded, then you cannot be charged. This also means that you cannot set a budget alert as you have no budget or spend.

On the Billing Account Overview page, look for the Credit info card.

If the Cloud Billing account is still limited to a Free Trial Cloud Billing account, you will see a Free trial credit info card.

This card displays the status of any remaining free trial credits, and provides an Upgrade button.

If the Cloud Billing account is upgraded to a paid account, you will see a Promotional credits info card.

This card displays the status of any remaining free trial credits. To view the details of the free trial, click Credit details.

Comment: thanks, once the free trial period ends does it automatically get upgraded to a paid account or does it remain on the free tier until I upgrade manually?

Comment: @tmpdev You must upgrade manually. At the end of 90 days, you must upgrade or close the account.

Comment: oh, I was under the impression that after 90 days you loose the free credits, but you still remain on the free tier until you upgrade to a paid account manually ?

Comment: @tmpdev Free Tier is a set of free services and that does not end provided you upgrade to a paid account. The Free Trial ends after 90 days at which point you must upgrade.

Comment: @tmpdev - You are welcome. If you want to learn more about Google Cloud Billing, I organized a series of short videos covering 20 different areas. https://www.jhanley.com/videolabs/Google-Cloud-Billing/